# Delete record with php then reload page

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a simple webpage that will allow the user to delete a record from a database and then the page will reload with the record deleted. Having trouble figuring out the code to use to accomplish this. Here is my main page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Change Record form</title>

<style type="text/css">
td {font-family: tahoma, arial, verdana; font-size: .875em }
</style>


</head>
<body>
<a href="add_new_form.php">Add new record</a>
<br>
<br>
<?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "customers");
     if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM music";

$rs = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

   // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row)
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";    
  echo $row['artist'] . "<br />";
  echo $row['title'] . "<br />";
  echo $row['format'] . "<br />";
  echo $row['notes'] . "<br />";

  echo '<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="update_form.php">
        <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Update">
        </FORM>';

  echo '<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="delete_process.php">
        <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Delete">
        </FORM>';
 }
?>
```

And then this is the delete_process page:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$artist = $_GET['artist'];
$title = $_GET['title'];
$format = $_GET['format'];
$notes = $_GET['notes'];

//create connection to DB
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "customers");

//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "DELETE from 'MUSIC' WHERE 'id' = $id";

mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Basically when the user clicks the delete button, that particular record will be deleted and the main page will reload with the record deleted. Don't really know the code, thanks!

Comment: first use prepared statements, column quotes are backticks not single quotes

Comment: I'm pretty sure `link` is not a valid form method. You should use `POST` and add a hidden field that contains the ID of the record you want to modify / delete.

Comment: `mysql_query($sql);` that one won't work. Including this `$sql = "DELETE from 'MUSIC' WHERE 'id' = $id";` - Point #1: Mixing APIs. Point #2: Wrong identifiers. Plus, what Jeroen said.

Comment: loading two pages just to delete one record is just too much, better use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

add a header at the end of your delete_process.php

```
<?php
//redirect to index page
header('Location:index.php'); //replace index.php with the page you want to redirect to
?>
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
'<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $row['id'] . '" />'
```

to the form that posts to delete_process.php.

However, you should know that the code as you've posted it is horribly insecure, and it would be trivial to attack via SQL injection and delete your entire database.